# how to permanently delete connections between nodes in dense layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to design the Neural Network which takes as a input few groups of parameters. I want Neural Network to analyze parameters in each group independently from other groups and then at some points merge all groups together.  All parameters in each group characterize the same process from different prospective but all groups are independent and I don't want to allow any leakage between groups till some point.
In other words I want nodes 1.1 and 1.2 (first layer) be linked only to nodes 2.1 and 2.2 (second layer) but not be linked to nodes 2.3 and 2.4. The same for nodes 1.3 and 1.4: they should be linked to 2.3 and 2.4, but should not communicate with 2.1 and 2.2

How to do that in Keras/tensorflow?

Comment: Please, add some code that shows what have you done so far.

Comment: What is done is sequential neural network with dense() layers which are fully connected. The question is how to make layers which are not fully connected? Dropout is not a right solution for this case (it is random). What I need is "controlled" dropout.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a sparsely connected layer. See here for a method to implement this in keras: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125907/keras-how-to-create-a-sparsely-connected-layer